# Can't login to pokemon go with google

Tags: pokemon-go

I love this game so much until yesterday.yesterday when i was logging in my account there was just a pokemonball running logo nothing happened for soooooo long.kept spinning.i don't know what to do and cried because i spent money on this game.i am using a note 5 android device.don't know why yhere is no recent devices.pls help me  . Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad situation. Can you give us some more information on what is happening? Have to tried to log in again since you first encountered this issue? Are you using a google account or a trainer club account? Did you try this with wifi and mobile data?

Comment: When i pressed google nothing happened just a pokemon ball spinning and i wauted for hours till nothing happened at all

Comment: Kill the cache of the game in your device's app settings and try again. This helped in the past. *When it asks for your birthday, don't click Ok without changing it properly.*

Comment: Dly tried your way but still had the running pokeball thingy.anyways ,thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I will give you advice but resource is only personal experience.

This problem affects Android 4.4.4 and the workaround is to create a Pokemon Trainer Club account (PTC).

After you create one, try loging in with your PTC, after you get in game, choose options and Sign Out. Now you should be able to log in with your google account.

Disclaimer: Even this work around doesn't work 100% of time, but alternating logins between PTC and Google (close application every time) should get it to work.

Comment: I should add that it is against Niantic's ToS to have multiple accounts, so it is possible (with no hard proof) that they may ban accounts that use the same Device. It's more of a heads up, since Niantic have been going after people who bot or use apps that access their servers outside of the game.  They may see this as something similar and ban you.

Comment: Good to know, didn't realize this. But their ToS should also include that you should be able to log in on supported OS and device.

Comment: I didn't hacked the game

Comment: Zikato i tried your way but can't login anyway thanks